# Advice on publishing VS MVC3 project to web server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ftp, publish, visual-studio-2012

As a company for years we have worked using old ASP (vbscript), we have just started updating to c# .net. our first MVC3 project is ready to be uploaded to the web server for testing and to iron out any bugs.

After reading about it I have made myself fairly familiar with the theory of it.

```
System.Web.Mvc

System.Web.Routing

System.Web.Abstractions
```

Have all been set to copy local 'true'

Right clicked the solution and selected 'Publish'

Created a new profile

Filled in the connection details, although I am unsure exactly what is meant by the '**Site Path**' and '**Destination URL**'

As it stands the site path is the scripting path and the destination URL is the URL as it would be typed into an address bar in a browser.

connection does validate.

in setting I have selected release

The there is a little tick box which seems scary to me, it says "**Delete all existing files prior to publish**" The server I am uploading to contains all our live and test websites, although I have created a new folder for the project, I under no circumstances want it to touch, edit, modify or delete anything else on the server. So this box is unchecked. Can anyone verify that leaving this unchecked will ensure it does nothing to anything else on the server?

Then in preview it simply says "Your application will be published to: (IP address of server)

Can anyone who has done this before give me some guidance this is the correct method to go? I could do it will less worries through a normal ftp but would like to be able to utilise Visual Studios tools. Its Visual Studio 2012.

Sorry if this isn't the exact correct place for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to do this for a while I discovered that publishing to ftp was a waste of time and the hard way to go about things. Although probably alot of you know this.

Instead I just published to a system file and then uploaded it with cuteftp to the web server. This maybe isn't the most professional way to go about things but from someone that comes from a primarily web scripting background, I found this alot less confusing and alot easier to manage.

I just thought I would answer my own question to resolve this thread.